# How to make a reusable function so that I keep the good practice of DRY?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

This is my code

```
  const renderEventStartEndDate = entry => {
    const { classes } = props;
    const isValidStartDate = isDateValid(entry.startDate);
    const isValidEndDate = isDateValid(entry.endDate);

    if (isValidStartDate && isValidEndDate && entry.startDate !== entry.endDate) {
      return (
        <div className={classes.textContainer}>
          {getFormattedEventDate(entry.startDate).toUpperCase()}

          {` TO ${getFormattedEventDate(entry.endDate).toUpperCase()}`}
        </div>
      );
    } else if (entry.startDate === entry.endDate && isValidStartDate && isValidEndDate) {
      return (
        <div className={classes.textContainer}>
          {getFormattedEventDate(entry.startDate).toUpperCase()}
        </div>
      );
    } else if ((isValidStartDate && !isValidEndDate) || (!isValidStartDate && isValidEndDate)) {
      if (isValidStartDate)
        return (
          <div className={classes.textContainer}>
            {getFormattedEventDate(entry.startDate).toUpperCase()}
          </div>
        );

      if (isValidEndDate)
        return (
          <div className={classes.textContainer}>
            {getFormattedEventDate(entry.endDate).toUpperCase()}
          </div>
        );
    }
```

I have an application and I want to reuse the above code so I am especially looking to reduce the return code here. I want to make a function like the one below and then use it in different components.

```
export const isDateValid = date => {
  const dateObj = new Date(date);
  return !isNaN(dateObj.getTime());
};
```

Comment: Try [codereview.stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You can set the three variables as parameters and call the function anywhere with the parameters you like to recieve

Comment: @MazharKhan Can you elaborate with code please?

Comment: It is always ok to repeat the code sometime, instead of trying to over optimising everything. Since, later you will be changing it often, then what you have optimised might change. The practice is if you have started to repeat it a few time, such as setting axios header for every post/put, or csrf token, then you have to optimise it and DRY, why because one edit is easier, that editing it everywhere. or else, that is the least worry. Start small, optimise when it grow.

Comment: check My answer, I know i should not write code. but lot of things has to be changed

Comment: Hahaha! :D https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Point taken @xdeepakv, haha :D

Answer (score 1):

Lot of refactor need, You can first separate, Business logic from View. Like parsing dates and creating string.

**Sample:**

```
const getDate = entry => {
  const isValidStartDate = isDateValid(entry.startDate);
  const isValidEndDate = isDateValid(entry.endDate);
  if (isValidStartDate && isValidEndDate && entry.startDate !== entry.endDate) {
    return `${getFormattedEventDate(
      entry.startDate
    ).toUpperCase()} TO ${getFormattedEventDate(entry.endDate).toUpperCase()}`;
  } else if (
    entry.startDate === entry.endDate &&
    isValidStartDate &&
    isValidEndDate
  ) {
    return `${getFormattedEventDate(entry.startDate).toUpperCase()}`;
  } else if (
    (isValidStartDate && !isValidEndDate) ||
    (!isValidStartDate && isValidEndDate)
  ) {
    if (isValidStartDate)
      return `${getFormattedEventDate(entry.startDate).toUpperCase()} `;
    if (isValidEndDate)
      return `${getFormattedEventDate(entry.endDate).toUpperCase()}`;
  }
};
const renderEventStartEndDate = entry => {
  const { classes } = props;
  return <div className={classes.textContainer}>{getDate(entry)}</div>;
};
```